# How to Navigate to a navigation menu item, programmatically, in React-Redux architecture design

Tags: reactjs, redux, browser-history, dispatch

I am using react redux to control the flow of data in my application. 
I have a very primitive initialState set. 
but I don't foresee the big picture of this file.

In my case, I actually want to navigate to a route when the user clicks on a navigation item in Navigator component. Right now, I directly import the history object and push the new state into History in the Navigator component.

I realize this is not correct for one, I have to do some CSS changes based on the selected navigation state and more. I understand that this information need to be flowing in from the store.

So how do I modify the above navigation process using the Redux Store and the React-redux data flow. How would I manipulate this information from the state of the store.

Comment: Can you create a bare bones code example of what you are doing and what you want to do? The question above is too generic

Comment: are you using react-router?